# Serve directory in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, server

I've got this basic python3 server but can't figure out how to serve a directory.

```
class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        def do_GET(self):
            print(self.path)
            if self.path == '/up':
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'Going Up')
            if self.path == '/down':
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(B'Going Down')

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Server started on ", PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

If Instead of the custom class above, I simply pass `Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` into TCPServer():, the default functionality is to serve a directory, but I want to serve that directory and have functionality on my two GETs above.

As an example, if someone were to go to localhost:8080/index.html, I'd want that file to be served to them

Comment: Please *always* use a generic [python] tag for any Python question. Use a version-specific tag if your question is version specific. Generally, on the python tag, it is assumed you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The simple way

You want to *extend* the functionality of `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`, so you **subclass** it! Check for your special condition(s), if none of them apply, call `super().do_GET()` and let it do the rest.

Example:

```
class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/up':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'up')
        else:
            super().do_GET()
```

### The long way

To serve files, you basically just have to open them, read the contents and send it.
To serve directories (indexes), use `os.listdir()`. (If you want, you can when receiving directories first check for an index.html and then, if that fails, serve an index listing).

Putting this into your code will give you:

```
class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        if self.path == '/up':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Going up')
        elif os.path.isdir(self.path):
            try:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(str(os.listdir(self.path)).encode())
            except Exception:
                self.send_response(500)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'error')
        else:
            try:
                with open(self.path, 'rb') as f:
                    data = f.read()
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(data)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                self.send_response(404)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'not found')
            except PermissionError:
                self.send_response(403)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'no permission')
            except Exception:
                self.send_response(500)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'error')
```

This example has a lot of error handling. You might want to move it somewhere else.
The problem is **this serves from *your root* directory**. To stop this, you'll have to (easy way) just add the serving directory to the beginning of `self.path`. Also check if `..` cause you to land higher than you want. A way to do this is `os.path.abspath(serve_from+self.path).startswith(serve_from)`

Putting this inside (after the check for /up):

```
class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.path)
        path = serve_from + self.path
        if self.path == '/up':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Going up')
        elif not os.path.abspath(path).startswith(serve_from):
            self.send_response(403)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b'Private!')
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            try:
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(str(os.listdir(path)).encode())
            except Exception:
                self.send_response(500)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'error')
        else:
            try:
                with open(path, 'rb') as f:
                    data = f.read()
                self.send_response(200)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(data)
            # error handling skipped
            except Exception:
                self.send_response(500)
                self.end_headers()
                self.wfile.write(b'error')
```

Note you define `path` and use it subsequently, otherwise you will still serve from /

Comment: long answer, but not really clear, where does serve_from come from ?

Answer (score 29):

if you are using 3.7, you can simply serve up a directory where your html files, eg. index.html is still

```
python -m http.server 8080 --bind 127.0.0.1 --directory /path/to/dir
```

for the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

Comment: Looks like plain `python -m http.server` also works

Comment: Is there a flag you need to add to get it to serve files in sub directories? I have a `.html` file that includes some `.js` scripts from a subfolder, using relative paths. This seems to work on apache and github pages, but the `GET`s return `404` when I test it with `python -m http.server` (loading in Firefox).

Comment: @MRule Where are you getting the 404, from the JS not being found or the html file? It is generally just serving up the directory structure eg very basic.

Comment: Sorry; I should delete my comment but I'll leave it up for posterity: The files were just missing. I forgot to initialize a git submodule. All is well.

Answer (score 3):

With python3, you can serve the current directory by simply running:

`python3 -m http.server 8080`

Of course you can configure many parameters as per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

Comment: Is there a flag you need to add to get it to serve files in sub directories? I have a `.html` file that includes some `.js` scripts from a subfolder, using relative paths. This seems to work on apache and github pages, but the `GET`s return `404` when I test it with `python -m http.server` (loading in Firefox).

Answer (score 1):

@user24343's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55053562/771768) to subclass `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` is really helpful! One detail I couldn't figure out was how to customize the `directory=` constructor arg when I pass `MyHandler` into `HTTPServer`. Use any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399394/771768), i.e.

```py
HTTPServer(('', 8001), lambda *_: MyHandler(*_, directory=sys.path[0]))
```