# Python HTTP Server serves only one file

Tags: python, apache, http

I am trying' to make a website using python HTTPServer, I know I could use any frameworks like flask or Django, but I don't want to.

The python code is:

```
from http import server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import json

# importing all the modules 

with open('settings.json', 'r') as json_file:
    setting = json.load(json_file)
    port = setting['port']
    start_at = setting['start_at']

# loading settings 

class Serv(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        
        try:
            file_to_open = open(start_at).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open = "File not found"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))

def start_server():
    """
    Starts the server
    """
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', port), Serv)
        print(f"[SERVER] Starting the server at port {port}")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f"[CLOSING] Closing the editor, see you again next time...")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server()
```

And when I try to serve it, the index.html file works perfectly but the icon and js files are not working. I know I could use the `python -m http.server` but I don't prefer to.

I will give some screenshots
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2qgA.png)

The app.js is displaying the same code in HTML but actually, I didn't write anything to the javascript file

Comment: It's because you are reading the same file each time, i.e., `file_to_open = open(start_at).read()`. You should get the requested file from the request and read that file.

Comment: Your server isn't even trying to serve any file other than `setting['start_at']`…?!

Comment: Hint: `path = self.translate_path(self.path)`

Answer (score 0):

This might help with your answer:
[Serve directory in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052811/serve-directory-in-python-3)

As others have said looks like you're opening the same file. To server other files, you need to parse `self.path` and open based on that.